# validating input if starts with "T" or "TP"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an input. I need to validate if the value starts with "T" followed by numbers or "TP" followed by numbers
Accepted values: T12345 or TP12345

My JavaScript code

```
var ip_value = document.getElementById('PROMASTER_NO_FW').value;
var v_first_char = ip_value.substr(0, 1);
var v_second_char = ip_value.substr(1, 1);

if (v_first_char.toUpperCase() !== 'T') {
  alert('It must be start with T');
  return false;
} else {
  if (v_second_char.toUpperCase !== 'P' && isNaN(Number(v_second_char))) {
    alert('error2');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Regex `/^TP?[0-9]{5}$/`

Comment: @Tushar It looks like the number is not limited to 5 chars length. "12345" is just for example. I may be wrong - it is pretty unclear.

Comment: `<input pattern="^TP?\d+$">` then add js validation if needed

Comment: Try `/^TP?[0-9]+$/` to force at least one number, or `/^TP?[0-9]*$/` if numbers are optional. Usage: `/^TP?[0-9]+$/.test("TP12345")`

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev From the OP _Accepted values: T12345 or TP12345_, looks like there are 5 digits. So used `{5}`

Comment: What is your question?  People are suggesting better approaches, but your information is incomplete and you don't actually ask a question.

Comment: @stephen my question is how to validate the inputs.. cause my codes isnt working

Comment: @pretzels04 Please show us the error you are getting with your script.

Comment: @anshul no error, but when i input other characters like AB still it accepting my inputs

Comment: I have posted an answer, your logic is correct and should work fine, check once my answer

Comment: I have added a snippet with few changes in your code, look at that

Comment: @AnshulMishra it is now working thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var ip_value = document.getElementById('test').value; //'AB12345';
    var v_first_char = ip_value.substr(0, 1);
    var v_second_char = ip_value.substr(1, 1);
    if (v_first_char.toUpperCase() !== 'T') {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'It must be start with T';
    } else if (v_second_char.toUpperCase() !== 'P' && isNaN(Number(v_second_char))) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'error2';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'no error';
    }
}
```

```html
It will work on blur <br />
<input type="text" id="test" onblur="myFunction()">
<span id="error">No Error</span>
```

I think your logic is perfect and should work fine, you just need to change:

```
v_second_char.toUpperCase
```

`to`

```
v_second_char.toUpperCase()
```

in last if condition

**Final  code will be**

```
var ip_value = document.getElementById('PROMASTER_NO_FW').value;
var v_first_char = ip_value.substr(0, 1);
var v_second_char = ip_value.substr(1, 1);

if (v_first_char.toUpperCase() !== 'T') {
  alert('It must be start with T');
  return false;
} else {
  if (v_second_char.toUpperCase() !== 'P' && isNaN(Number(v_second_char))) { //change in this line
    alert('error2');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Or for the short line of code you can use the regular expression as shown in above answers.**

Answer (score 0):

You  can use regular expression to achieve your scenario.

```
var reg = new RegExp(/^TP?[0-9]+$/)

if((string).match(reg))
    return true
else 
    return false
```

The condition in the `if` statement can also be used to retrieve the match string from the original string provided.

Comment: `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` can _always_ be reduced to `return (condition);`

Comment: But here `condition` returns the matched string not `true` or `false`.

Comment: ... and if nothing matches it returns a _falsey_ null, not false — I _keep_ forgetting about that. Ok... `return ( string.match(reg) != null );`

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching against a regular expression would be the best thing to use here. Assuming you are returning true if and only if `ip_value` is a 'T' or 'TP' followed by at least one number:

```
var ip_value = document.getElementById('PROMASTER_NO_FW').value;
var pattern = new RegExp(/^TP?\d+$/);
return pattern.test(ip_value);
```

`/^TP?\d+$/` is the regular expression pattern or regex for short - if you're not familiar with regexes, a good starting point in the context of Javascript is the [MDN Regular Expressions Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).